# Get username and password (Unencrypted) in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I can get the password (not encrypted) through OncePerRequestFilter, however, I would like to get it in a normal class of type @Controller. Follow the code.

My Form:

```
<form action="/security/login" method="post">

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username" required>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Acessar</button>
</form>
```

The class I currently use to get the information after login:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {  

private String pass; 
private String user;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

if ("/security/login".equals(request.getRequestURI()) && request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("post")) {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    
    if (username != null && password != null) {
        request.setAttribute("username", username);
        request.setAttribute("password", password);
        
        user = username;
        pass = password;
        
        login.setUsername(username);
        System.out.println("User Login: "+user+" Password: "+pass);
    }
}        
chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```